# Focus move between two fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, leanback

Hello friends I am developing an Tv application in which screen have two visible fragments.
Let my first FragmentA have RecyclerView with Grid orientation and same in FragmentB.
And
FragmentA have focus now i want to move to fragmentB by using DPAD navigation.

But i am unable to move fragmentB.
is it possible to move. if "yes" please advice. else Please advice for alternate of it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the focus of the parent layout of the recycler item and add these only to the recycler view that has to be focused or higlighted while DPAD navigation is done.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```